# I want bring nodes forward in the following code

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\coordinate (1) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (2) at (1,1);
\coordinate (3) at (1,-1);
\coordinate (4) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (5) at (0,2.8);
\coordinate (6) at (2.8,0);
\coordinate (7) at (0,-2.8);
\coordinate (8) at (-2.8,0);
\fill[black!100, draw=black, thick] (1) circle (1.5pt) node[black, below right] {$x_1$};
\fill[black!100, draw=black, thick] (2) circle (1.5pt) node[black, below left] {$x_3$};
\fill[black!100, draw=black, thick] (3) circle (1.5pt) node[black, above left] {$x_5$};
\fill[black!100, draw=black, thick] (4) circle (1.5pt) node[black, above right] {$x_7$};
\fill[black!100, draw=black, thick] (5) circle (1.5pt) node[black, above] {$x_2$};
\fill[black!100, draw=black, thick] (6) circle (1.5pt) node[black, right] {$x_4$};
\fill[black!100, draw=black, thick] (7) circle (1.5pt) node[black, below] {$x_6$};
\fill[black!100, draw=black, thick] (8) circle (1.5pt) node[black, left] {$x_8$};
\draw[fill opacity=0.7,fill=gray] (1) -- (2) --  (5);
\draw[fill opacity=0.7,fill=gray] (2) -- (3) --  (6);
\draw[fill opacity=0.7,fill=gray] (3) -- (4) --  (7);
\draw[fill opacity=0.7,fill=gray] (4) -- (1) --  (8);
\draw[fill opacity=0.7,fill=gray] (2) -- (6) --  (5);
\draw[fill opacity=0.7,fill=gray] (3) -- (7) --  (6);
\draw[fill opacity=0.7,fill=gray] (4) -- (8) --  (7);
\draw[fill opacity=0.7,fill=gray] (1) -- (5) --  (8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bring forward" exactly?

Comment: I mean the nodes are behind the edges, I want to bring them forward.

Comment: Just draw the nodes after the edges. Also, please always include a complete ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: The nodes, i.e. the text labels, are not behind the edges when I try your code. If you mean the dots (which are not nodes in the TikZ sense), they are behind the edges and filled areas because they are drawn before them. Move all  the `\fill` lines to after the `\draw` lines to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion how to solve your problem is already suggested in comments, so below is example how you can write more concise code for your image. In it are considered above comments:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt,
              label=#1, node contents={}}
                    ]
\coordinate (1) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (2) at (1,1);
\coordinate (3) at (1,-1);
\coordinate (4) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (5) at (0,2.8);
\coordinate (6) at (2.8,0);
\coordinate (7) at (0,-2.8);
\coordinate (8) at (-2.8,0);
\draw[fill opacity=0.7,fill=gray]
        (1) -- (2) --  (5)
        (2) -- (3) --  (6)
        (3) -- (4) --  (7)
        (4) -- (1) --  (8)
        (2) -- (6) --  (5)
        (3) -- (7) --  (6)
        (4) -- (8) --  (7)
        (1) -- (5) --  (8);
\path   (1) node[dot=below right: $x_1$]
        (2) node[dot=below left: $x_3$]
        (3) node[dot=above left: $x_5$]
        (4) node[dot=above right: $x_7$]
        (5) node[dot=above: $x_2$]
        (6) node[dot=right: $x_4$]
        (7) node[dot=below: $x_6$]
        (8) node[dot=left: $x_8$];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution but using two square nodes instead of particular coordinates

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, thick, fill=gray, fill opacity=0.7, rotate=45,
    label={north east:$x_2$}, 
    label={north west:$x_8$}, 
    label={south west:$x_6$}, 
    label={south east:$x_4$}, minimum size=4cm] (out) {};
\node[draw, thick, fill=white,
    label={[anchor=north west]north west:$x_1$}, 
    label={[anchor=north east]north east:$x_3$}, 
    label={[anchor=south east]south east:$x_5$},
    label={[anchor=south west]south west:$x_7$}, minimum size=2cm] (in) {};
\foreach \i in {south east, south west, north east, north west}
    \foreach \j in {in, out}
        \filldraw[black] (\j.\i) circle(2pt);
\draw (out.north east) edge (in.north west) edge (in.north east);
\draw (out.north west) edge (in.north west) edge (in.south west);
\draw (out.south west) edge (in.south west) edge (in.south east);
\draw (out.south east) edge (in.south east) edge (in.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]